# My cat is acting strange

Tags: cats, behavior, scratching

My cat is almost a year old. I got her when she was just between six and seven weeks old. She has been the perfect cat.  She loves me to pieces and she is great with the kids.

We moved about two and a half months ago and about a month ago she started to show some, I'm not sure if I should call it aggression, it seems like she's scared all of a sudden. She has been jumpy lately as well.

She is still very social and wants to be held all the time but silly things seem to scare her now. Even me setting my phone down next to her if she's not totally paying attention and she's laying in my lap will scare her.

I feel like it's not me because she always wants to be around me and cuddle and have her belly rubbed. Just randomly she will freak out and scratch me for no apparent reason. She can be in the other room doing her own thing and she will just run in here to scratch me and then run away.  I don't know if it's the move or what it is.

Just now she was in the living room looking out the sliding glass door, she started to walk this way and out of the blue she got spooked and scratched me. My arm was dripping blood. Any ideas?

Could this be just adjusting to a new home? Did something happen that I just haven't noticed? I love my cat to pieces but if she starts scratching the kids like this I don't know if she will be able to stay. My arms and legs are covered in scratches.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sounds very much like cat behaviour, and nothing too alarming, although the excessive scratching is a bit of a worry. Cats do vary a lot and do strange things. Mine will sit in a corridor and stare at the wall a few inches away, sometimes he will dart in and out of the room, sometimes he will scratch me as he wants food. I walk him to his bowl (which is full) and he's fine and eats--he just wants a chaperone? *shrugs*

Cats like to choose when they interact, too. Are they scratching you after you play with them too much? Cats like a bit of attention but will tell you when it's too much. Mine will softly nip my hand to say "hey back off dude"... if I continue I will get swiped. If I touch his belly more than a couple times he will swipe me as well.

It could very much be adjusting to a new home. If you have anything that makes her feel comfortable and at ease such as an old blanket she used to sit on, then give her that? I would also say you could try some of the pheromone products like [Feliway cats](https://www.feliway.com/uk).

Answer (score 4):

This behavior shows that it got scared by something. It can happen while playing, or of a noise, or if it got hit (or hit itself). Before you start worrying, don't. My cat hit himself as he tried to run through a closed door when he got scared while playing. The vets assured me it will take time for this to pass. He started to avoid the room and place where it all happened, but now (one month after) he is back to normal. Still a bit jumpy but that is OK.

Showing signs of affection, letting her be petted, not hiding in dark places is a good sign. If she plays that means she is OK.
She should eat and drink water. She should also user her litter box. If you notice she stops doing any of those, consult a vet.

If she is not spayed, she may also become a little aggressive. It is rare with females, but possibility. After six months to a year, you can speak with your vet about the procedure.

Other than that, give her time. She will get better.